# jQuery GeoComplete - init location by lat and long

Tags: jquery, google-maps, maps

Any idea how to `init` the location (so the pin is dropped) with `GeoComplete`?

```
 $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
    map: ".map_canvas",
    location: [52.4078567, 16.92718339999999], // is it centring the map, no pin thought
    markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
    },
    details: "form",
    types: ["geocode", "establishment"]

});
```

**The example above does center the map, but is it not dropping a pin**. Why?
Online demo [here](http://testowy.site44.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pin does not appear to be placed when you specify a longitude and latitude on initialization.

The alternative is to remove the location option from the initialization, and do a once-off search of your default location just after you have created the geocomplete instance:

```
// Run this function once after the first search
$("#geocomplete").geocomplete(options)
  .one("geocode:result", function(event, result){

    // Set the zoom level you require for the default map
    var map = $("#geocomplete").geocomplete("map");
    map.setZoom(13);

    // Optionally empty the geocomplete input field
    $("#geocomplete").val("");

});
```

Followed by a find by address:

```
$("#geocomplete").geocomplete("find", "Poznań, Poland");
```

Or by longitude and latitude:

```
var lat_and_long = "52.4078567, 16.9271833";
$("#geocomplete").geocomplete("find", lat_and_long);
```

Comment: The marker missing is a known issue btw: https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/issues/13

Comment: Can you do find by LAT and LON, not by location name?

Comment: @mccannf this does not seem to work. Running `$("#geocomplete").geocomplete("find", "55.737196917624196, 12.508628716918793");` in console, here: http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/map.html

Comment: @mccannf, didn't worked for me either. not opening the map exactly on last selected coordinates.